# I want to get the data of individual districts from the json fromat with js

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
  "Haryana": {
    "districtData": {
      "Italians": {
        "notes": "Italian tourists who were treated in Haryana",
        "active": 0,
        "confirmed": 14,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 14,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "Ambala": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 2,
        "confirmed": 14,
        "deceased": 1,
        "recovered": 11,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },

      "Yamunanagar": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 1,
        "confirmed": 4,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 3,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 1,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "statecode": "HR"
  },
```

I want the data of the districts from these states separately 
i am unable to get the data district wise 
the data needs to like this
district name:
active:
death:
decovered:
.....etc

the data needs to de stored differently and displayed

Comment: Use JSON.parse(text). See tutorial here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Comment: please show us your expected format.